# how can i make the player run in a certain path ? i already had the animation

Tags: animation, game-engine

i am beginner in working with blender game engine , i already had the character and its animation , in the BGE the action is done only once i wanna know how to make it do the action as long the key pressed and also in certain path , any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you play a looping walking cycle (on place) and It's the parent at the same time.

The resulting animation looks like walking.